# NTFS junctions fail after SysPrep

Tags: windows, sysprep, ntfs-junction

I have a system with numerous partitions across several physical disks. After a Windows SysPrep the drive letters are re-assigned (this is expected), so I have a script that re-letters them back to the way they were. Everything is fine except that our NTFS junctions (symlinks) no longer function.

After SysPrepping, the junctions on C: are reset to point back to themselves.I verified this with a quick `fsutil reparsepoint query <junctionName>`

How can I restore the drive letter assignments such that out NTFS junctions will function again?